# Can I limit my Bluemix utilization and charges?

Tags: ibm-cloud, price

Imagine I wish to prototype a Bluemix application or simply wish to learn Bluemix.  I understand that many of its services have free thresholds before any charges are accrued.  Is there a way to set thresholds on my Bluemix account such that I am warned before exceeding free limits?  Can I constrain my account such that it will disable services before charges are accrued or otherwise automate the mechanical constraint of my Bluemix utilization?

A potential example of such a need might be for the hobbyist who is self studying but does not want to incur charges or for the programmer who makes a logic error that results in excessive resource consumption or for the user who accidentally neglects to shutdown a resource consuming application after testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are spending limits for paid accounts. According to the documentation, "you can set or edit notifications for total account, runtime, and service spending, as well as spending for individual services, excluding third-party services. You receive notifications when you reach 80%, 90%, and 100% of the spending thresholds you specify."

Comment: The Bluemix pricing calculator provides service-by-service details on what is free and what the charges are. https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?direct=classic/&cm_mc_uid=67466847845814472525610&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1456177183#/pricing/cloudOEPaneId=pricing&paneId=pricingSheet&orgGuid=83b104ed-b317-41ec-ada9-45430ed967ce&spaceGuid=6e1823a9-0f99-4438-829b-b32ed4b01ae1

Comment: Howdy guys ... thanks for the responses.  The information about being notified of thresholds is great and the calculation of how much I will pay for fee based utilization is also great.  What remains is my query on "fearless" playing.  I find myself with a concern that I will "accidentally" incur a charge while playing.  What I want to have happen is have a "lock" on my usage such that I will not be allowed to exceed a threshold ... which may be zero dollars.  Is that capability possible?

Comment: @Kolban As far as I can tell from their documentation, no, there's no way to set a hard limit on your monthly expenses.